# phpmyadmin: I can connect my site via localhost (XAMPP) but not with my hosting

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, mysqli, phpmyadmin

I will try to explain my problem the best I can:

I was given a working site and asked for a replication to another hosting.
My first thought was that it was too simple. So first I tried to make it work via XAMPP:

1. Downloaded all the site from the hosting via FTP
2. Changed the values of the database connection (The site was created with CodeIgniter)

After this I opened it on my browser and it worked perfect! (localhost/mysite)

So, now it worked, I tried connecting to my hosting phpmyadmin:

1. Exported the database from actual phpmyadmin and imported to the new phpmyadmin.
2. Changed the values of the database connection to the new phpmyadmin

And here is where i got stuck. The site stopped working and I can't figured out why. The database was imported with a new name, but on my database connection i put the values correct (copy-paste to avoid troubles) but the site won't open.
The problem I have with this site is that has some sort of configuration (i assume javascript) where the site gets stuck on "loading" until it connects to the database. So i don't know where to use mysqli functions to get an error and try to know where is my mistake.

I think thats all. I hope someone can help me with this!

Comment: do you get any errors?

Comment: What means "site won't open". Have you put some research afford to get any error messages? PHP or server error Log?

Comment: That's my problem. I have never used CodeIgniter, so i can't get any error.

Comment: If you need any screenshots or anything please tell me and i will give you asap. Thanks!

Comment: PHP error log has nothing to do with the used framework. We do not need a screenshot. We need an error message to help you.

Comment: You are right. My problem is that I'm still learning OOP, I only know how to code PHP with procedural.

Comment: I've Tried this to get an error. I used another site, without framework, just an index.php with this code
<?php
    const SERVER = 'localhost';
    const USUARIO = 'x';
    const CLAVE = 'x';
    const BASE = 'x';

    $link = mysqli_connect(SERVER, USUARIO, CLAVE, BASE) or die("");
    mysqli_set_charset($link, 'utf8');
?>

If I put my XAMPP values, it works fine, but if i use my hosting values i get this error:

Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user '207760-brube'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/x.php on line 7

Answer (score 1):

Solved!
I believe the problem was that i tried to connect to "localhost" using the hosting Phpmyadmin and not the localhost one.
I've uploaded the site to the new hosting and it worked.
Thanks anyways to everyone, it made me think differently to get the problem solved.